# Delphi XE5, MYSQL, x86 and x64 single solution

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe5, dbexpress

I've had this working in (most) previous versions of Delphi, but I can't find the right combinations of dbexpress DLLs and DB versions for XE5.

Has anyone figured out the which combinations of the following work together with Delphi XE5?

1) MySQL Database Version
2) x86 Vendor lib
3) x64 vendor lib
4) Delphi XE5

Currently I have connectivity from my 32-bit apps, but the x64 apps will not connect.

Comment: What have you actually tried? What problems are you actually having? You need to be more specific.

Comment: I guess my question was... if there's ANYONE out there who has it working at all, I'd like to know what it is that they're using.  Because seriously, every new release of Delphi involves me juggling DLLs for days... sometimes weeks.... in this case... months.  It is obviously way too much for us to ask that Delphi simply come with a MySQL connector that works with the latest version of MySQL.  If you have a working client that works with exe's targeting both x86 and x64.  I'd love to know that it is even POSSIBLE.

Comment: I am absolutely amazed that there is no answer for this right now.  I think this is a big FAIL for Embarcadero.  ;)